# How would I make my table/page into a responsive one?

Tags: css, responsive-design

As the title suggest, I would like to make my table into a responsive one so that it can auto adjust itself on either a mobile device or desktop. Here's my code:

```css
article, aside, figure, footer, header,
menu, nav, section { display: block; }
body {
    font-size: 1em;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 100%;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 100%;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: red;
    text-align: center;
}

td {
    min-width: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    text-align: center;

    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    vertical-align: top;
}

th {
    border: 2px solid #cccccc;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>User ID</th>
        <th>Website</th>
        <th>Time</th>
        <th>Data Usage</th>
        <th>Total Data Usage</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><h2><span style="cursor:pointer">Luke</span></h2></td>
        <td><p>Facebook</p><p>Youtube</p></td>
        <td><p>10.00am</p><p>1.30pm</p></td>
        <td><p>3mb</p><p>1gb</p></td>
        <td><h3>1.3gb</h3></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><h2><span style="cursor:pointer">John</span></h2></td>
        <td><p>Facebook</p><p>Youtube</p></td>
        <td><p>10.00am</p><p>1.30pm</p></td>
        <td><p>3mb</p><p>1gb</p></td>
        <td><h3>1.3gb</h3></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><h2><span style="cursor:pointer">Peter</span></h2></td>
        <td><p>Facebook</p><p>Youtube</p></td>
        <td><p>10.00am</p><p>1.30pm</p></td>
        <td><p>3mb</p><p>1gb</p></td>
        <td><h3>1.3gb</h3></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I have tried using JQuery but I think I may have done it wrongly haha. Any help would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: See this codepen in my codepens collections http://codepen.io/chriseppstein/pen/bprmt

Comment: Thank you very much Phiter! You're a life saver!!!

Comment: Lotusms your code collections worked as well thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use "vw" or "vh" which basically is 1% of your viewing width and viewing height as a scale instead of pixels. It is currently supported by most web browsers, so compatibility shouldn't be much of a worry.

For example:

```
#test {
 width:25vw;
 height:25vh;
 position:absolute;
 top:25vw;
 left:25vh;
 background-color:rgba(127,127,127,0.5);
}
```

and

```
<div id="test"></div>
```